# I want to make string data calculator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This code is any wrong output
input="11.10*4"
output=40
It is solved
Making a calculator whose input is a string ***without using eval***

my new problem is if first value is operator like +10-5 or -10/5 output NaN.

How can solve this problem ?

Another problem:
10-+5 or 10++55
I think for this problem but it is not solve function is not return true value.

```
const hatatespit = (str) => {
        const _error=['--','+-','//','**','-+','++'];
        let asd;
        while(_error.includes(str))
        {
            asd=str.replace('--','+');
            asd=str.replace('-+','-');
            asd=str.replace('+-','-');
            asd=str.replace('//','/');
            asd=str.replace('**','*');
            asd=str.replace('++','+');
            
        }
        return asd;
    };
```

//

```js
const calcute = str => {
  const deger = [];
  const operator = [];
  const Numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "."];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    
    if (Numbers.includes(str[i])) {
      let arabellek = "";
      while (i < str.length && Numbers.includes(str[i])) {
        arabellek += str[i];
        i++;
      }

      deger.push(parseFloat(arabellek));
      i--;

    } else if (str[i] === '(') {

      operator.push(str[i]);

    } else if (str[i] === ')') {

      while (operator[operator.length - 1] !== '(') {

        deger.push(hesapla(operator.pop(), deger.pop(), deger.pop()));
      }
      operator.pop();
    } 
       else if (str[i] === '+' || str[i] === '-' || str[i] === '*' || str[i] === '/') {

      while (operator.length && islemOnceligi(str[i], operator[operator.length - 1])) {
        
        deger.push(hesapla(operator.pop(), deger.pop(), deger.pop()));
      }

      operator.push(str[i]);
    }

  }
  while (operator.length) {

    deger.push(hesapla(operator.pop(), deger.pop(), deger.pop()));
  }
  return deger.pop();
};
const islemOnceligi = (op1, op2) => {
  if (op2 === '(' || op2 == ')') {
    return false;
  }
  if ((op1 === '*' || op1 === '/') && (op2 === '+' || op2 === '-')) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
const hesapla = (op, y, x) => {
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      return parseFloat(x + y);
    case '-':
      return parseFloat(x - y);
    case '*':
      return parseFloat(x * y);
    case '/':
      if (y === 0) {
        throw 'Sıfıra bölüm hatası!';
      }
      return parseFloat(x / y);

  }
  return 0;
};
var cumle = prompt("HESAPLAMAK İSTEDİNİZ İSLEMİ GİRİN");
document.write(calcute(cumle));
```

```html
<h2>CALCULATOR</h2>
```

Comment: You should some kind of regex. You drop the decimal point.

Comment: Can't I do it without using regex?

Comment: You are writing a parser. You have an issue with full stop being ignored. You need to fix that first

Comment: I don't know how do this because I am beginner. Do you any recomment for me ?

Comment: This is bound to have issues anyway. How do you differentiate between a user trying to subtract or trying to write a negative number? What if a user enters 2 or more operators after each other?

Comment: so what do you recommend?
maybe this issue can be ignored as i am a beginner.

Comment: I'd recommend making a visual input instead. It'll make it a bit easier for you. String input is certainly possible, but you'll have to setup some rules. Like a space between values and operators is required, for example: `3 + -10 * 4`. Now you can split on the space character and differentiate between operators and negative numbers. If multiple operators are found after each other, you can make a rule that it should be considered a correction and simply ignore all operators except the last one etc.

Comment: I thought this way, if it is +-, the string can also remove those inputs and add - instead, or if it is --, + instead.

Comment: what if there is an input like 1/-1 ?
what should I do ?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If the question was why it's 40 than simply change "hasOwnProperty()" to "includes()" e.g.:

```
const calcute = str => {
  const deger = [];
  const operator = [];
  const Numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "."];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (Numbers.includes(str[i])) {
      let arabellek = "";
      while (i < str.length && Numbers.includes(str[i])) {
        arabellek += str[i];
        i++;
      }
      deger.push(parseFloat(arabellek));
      i--;
    } else if (str[i] === '(') {
      operator.push(str[i]);
    } else if (str[i] === ')') {
      while (operator[operator.length - 1] !== '(') {
        deger.push(hesapla(operator.pop(), deger.pop(), deger.pop()));
      }
      operator.pop();
    } else if (str[i] === '+' || str[i] === '-' || str[i] === '*' || str[i] === '/') {
      while (operator.length && islemOnceligi(st1 + r[i], operator[operator.length - 1])) {
        deger.push(hesapla(operator.pop(), deger.pop(), deger.pop()));
      }
      operator.push(str[i]);
    }
  }
  while (operator.length) {
    deger.push(hesapla(operator.pop(), deger.pop(), deger.pop()));
  }
  return deger.pop();
};
const islemOnceligi = (op1, op2) => {
  if (op2 === '(' || op2 == ')') {
    return false;
  }
  if ((op1 === '*' || op1 === '/') && (op2 === '+' || op2 === '-')) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
const hesapla = (op, y, x) => {
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      return parseFloat(x + y);
    case '-':
      return parseFloat(x - y);
    case '*':
      return parseFloat(x * y);
    case '/':
      if (y === 0) {
        throw 'Sıfıra bölüm hatası!';
      }
      return parseFloat(x / y);

  }
  return 0;
};
var cumle = prompt("HESAPLAMAK İSTEDİNİZ İSLEMİ GİRİN");
document.write(calcute(cumle));
```